# Active Record Association - Can't seem to get this to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie to Ruby (2.2.3) on Rails (4.2.4) and am trying to set the following Active Record Association:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organizers, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organized_events, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: "organizer_id"
end
```

When I use the association u.events, (where u = User.first as an example) I successfully get a list of events associated with that user. But when I use e.organizers (where e = Event.first as an example) I get Nil back even though there is an organizer associated with event e (and the organizer has a proper foreign key organizer_id in events table).

No sure what is going wrong. Appreciate if you can provide some insight into why e.organizers is not returning the valid organizer but just returning a nil instead.

Thanks in advance. If the issue needs any further elaboration, do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get e.organizers the following change worked:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :organized_events, class_name: "Event"
 end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizers, class_name: "User"
end

class EventsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
create_table :events_users, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
  t.belongs_to :event, index: true
end
end
```

Changing the Active Record association as above, allowed me to get e.organizers.

I inspected the generated associations through the pry-rails debugger and was able to confirm the same:

Event::GeneratedAssociationMethods#methods: 
organizer_ids
organizer_ids=
organizers
organizers=

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined that an `Organizer` or `User` `belongs_to` an `Event`, you should be calling `event.organizer` or `event.user`.

To keep things a lot simpler why not try the following (as you really should have no need to be specifying the class_name and FK in this type of simple association (I personally feel).

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

---

If you prefer the naming you specified then why not:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :organizer 
end

class Organizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

---

Note the that in the above examples `belongs_to :organizer` and `belongs_to :user` in singular.

Comment: Ben. Appreciate your suggestions. The suggested examples are different from the use case, since using the alias of organizers allows me to distinguish from users who aren't organizers. Bear in mind that a single model is being used in this design for users and organizers which is User.